# I can't uninstall 6 apps, but I have never seen them before

Tags: 20.04, uninstall

Hey guys I have Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS and I recently found out that some apps have showed up on my app list. How would I remove 'Echomixer', 'Envy24 control', 'Envy24 Control', 'HDAJackRetask', 'HDSPConf', 'HDSPMixer'.
There are two Envy24 controls but one has a thumbnail, and one doesn't.
Are these viruses?
When I do sudo apt-get remove (app), it doesn't work, and when I manually drag it into the rubbish bin it says access denied, but my user is an Administrator....
How do I fix this???

Comment: All of these are audio packages. Have you been doing things with PulseAudio or ALSA? There's a possibility these were installed as dependencies when something else was brought in. You might find out when/why these were installed by looking at the `/var/log/apt/history.log` file.

Answer (score 3):

All of these apps were installed by the same package (alsa-tools-gui). The locations of their executable files are `/usr/bin/echomixer`, `/usr/bin/envy24control`, `/usr/bin/hdajackretask`, `/usr/bin/hdspconf` and `/usr/bin/hdspmixer`. Running `apt policy alsa-tools-gui` will tell you if
alsa-tools-gui is installed, which I expect it to be because echomixer, envy24control, hdajackretask, hdspconf and hdspmixer are unique to the alsa-tools-gui package in the default Ubuntu 20.04 repositories.

To uninstall alsa-tools-gui open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove alsa-tools-gui
```

Comment: They [have desktop](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/alsa-tools-gui/filelist) files, so they are **apps** .